# More visible tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Would it be an idea to change how tags are displayed on a question?
Make them more visible.

It is not a big issue, but seems like people, *(me included – though 
I'm better now)*, sometimes jump to fast and overlook the tags. Guess
they disappear a bit among the "*share edit retag flag*" links.

Find e.g. [superuser](http://superuser.com) tags to be much better.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

I understand the need for consistency – as in same layout for tags everywhere,
and as such I find the listing under e.g. *"[/questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions)"* for Unix & Linux
to be better again, – but there should perhaps be a way to make them stand out
a bit more on the Q/A pages.

Comment: Yes, even some bold or larger font could be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree - especially for those with *a)* crappy monitors and/or *b)* visual issues requiring high contrast. I regularly use five different SE sites, and all have more easily-identified tags than U&L. Right now, the tags here are set to `background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240)`. Adjusting it down to 200 or so looks much better, at least to me:

[image: I apologize, I only have MS Paint on my work computer...]

Comment: Though that makes the tag itself harder to read, because it reduces the contract between text color and background.

Comment: They're now 230 - slightly darker, but still enough contrast to read the text.